# Error while installing Cocoapods: [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `cocoapods' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007fa8a339cd78>

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

I am installing cocoapods for a udemy course. Im new to terminal and new to iOS development. I do not have native react installed and many of the answers online seem to refer to that program. Cocoapods initiated but won't install after setting the platform. Here are the contents of the podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do
  use_frameworks!

   

> Pods for Flash Chat iOS13

  
  gem install cocoapods

end
```

After running pod install I get this error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `cocoapods' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007fa8a339cd78>.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fount this error while installing [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `xxw' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007ff33baba230>.